# MVC routing vs angularjs routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, angularjs-routing

While MVC itself has routing feature why should we use angularjs routing? I am expecting an answer apart from just addressing server side and client side issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a design decision, so it's impossible to give a definitive answer as to why you should use one or the other. MVC has its own routing because it's a server-side web application framework. AngularJS has its own routing because it's a client-side web application framework. You can use one or the other or both in mixed degrees. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting, but it entirely boils down to whether you want to rely more on server-side or client-side, and even then, *where* and to what degree. You could have portions of your site that rely entirely on Angular and essentially function as a SPA, while other parts would rely entirely on MVC with nothing going on client-side.